# How to list only assignable video categories youtube v3?

Tags: api, youtube

Using v2 of the API via: http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat, I can see both assignable and deprecated video categories.

However, using the v3 google data API, I see all categories, but no flag indicating if they are usable as a category on a video upload.  Case in point is the category labelled "Anime/Animation" (category 31). If you try to upload a video using this category, you will receive a "Bad Request" response from YT at the end of the upload process.

If you choose any of the categories in the "assignable" list as per the first URL, then the upload works. Here's a deprecated category using the Atom based API:

```
<atom:category term="Movies_anime_animation" label="Anime/Animation" xml:lang="en-US">
    <yt:deprecated/>
</atom:category>
```

Here's the same thing, in JSON, from the Google API Explorer:

```
{
"id": "31",
"kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
"etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/-p_eJg3ji5PiNMcZrzS4hNfl4gQ\"",
"snippet": {
    "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ",
    "title": "Anime/Animation"
}
```

I've looked at the video.list v3 API docs, and also the raw JSON output from the same API. I can't see how I could differentiate between deprecated and assignable categories. Is this just plain missing from the API or have I missed something?

Comment: Have you resolved this any further? While you can use the v2 XML interface to get a list of assignable categories, it's difficult to correlate this info with the list provided by the v3 interface. Using the category title to match things up is problematic. For example, there are currently 2 "Comedy" categories, one of which is assignable and the other deprecated. There doesn't seem to be a way to determine which of the v3 "Comedy" categories to eliminate. What did you end up doing?

Comment: I've had to use v3 to get categories, and then further resolve those "upload able" using the v2 API. It's pretty awful imho. Can't see a way around it yet tho, as the v3 API simply doesn't appear to expose the required info.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive the list of assignable categories parsing XML document. This is an example on **PHP**:

```
$catURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat';
$cxml = simplexml_load_file($catURL);
$cxml->registerXPathNamespace('atom', 'http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom');
$result = $cxml->xpath('//atom:category/yt:assignable/..');

$categories = array();
foreach ($result as $row) $categories[(string)$row['term']] = (string)$row['label'];
```

Comment: Yes, clearly. Except my question is "how to do this in v3 API?".  I'm aware of how to do it in v2 API.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles upon this question: YouTube V3 API now returns an assignable flag with each category snippet.

**Request**

```sh
curl \
  'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=snippet&regionCode=NL&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --compressed
```

**Response**

```json
{
    "kind": "youtube#videoCategory",
    "etag": "7mqChSJogdF3hSIL-88BfDE-W8M",
    "id": "17",
    "snippet": {
        "title": "Sports",
        "assignable": true,
        "channelId": "UCBR8-60-B28hp2BmDPdntcQ"
    }
}
```